# Ajax post delayed by alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I use the following code to send an action and parameter to a script on my server:

```
$(function() {
    url = "http://...../myscript.php";
    $.post(url, { action: 'my action', param: 'my parameter'}, {cache: false});
    alert("Hello");
});
```

I noticed (on Safari 6.0.4 on MacOSX) the alert box pops up and the ajax request is only sent *after* I click "OK". (On Chrome the request is sent while the alert is displayed).

So the code *following* my ajax request actually delays the request being sent.

Why is this?

Edit:

```
$.post(url, { action: 'system', param: 'volume get 5'}, {cache: false});
sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    sum++;
$("title").html(sum);
```

Causes the request to be sent after the calculation is done.

Comment: Because alert() is a blocking action. The post is sent, the alert then stops the browser from processing the result (remember, ajax is asynchronous) until you close the alert. You aren't delaying the request being sent, you're delaying the request being received.

Comment: @KevinB To clarify, you are delaying the callback functions from executing, not the response being received.

Comment: @KevinB I'd expect the browser blocking any callbacks or similar, but that there is no outgoing request seems strange?

Comment: @KevinB and Samuel: I bet it's the `onreadystate` callbacks being sent to jQuery. The browser starts the send, but then hits the `alert`, and then wants to send an `onreadystate` event to the JavaScript layer. That event callback waits to be dequeued by the JavaScript thread, and (apparently) holds up the ajax call... That's the only explanation I can see for why Samuel is seeing the *sending* get delayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed (on Safari 6.0.4 on MacOSX) the alert box pops up and the ajax request is only sent after I click "OK". (On Chrome the request is sent while the alert is displayed).
>
> So the code following my ajax request actually delays the request being sent.

I find that very surprising, but I can't test it as I don't have Mac OS X. Although `alert` blocks the main JavaScript thread, it shouldn't prevent the browser from **sending** the request, as the browser is multi-threaded. But I suppose it could, in some implementations.

Note that regardless, `alert` will hold up the call to any "success" or "error" handlers you have associated with the request, which is a completely different thing. This is because unless you use web workers, JavaScript is single-threaded on browsers, and (again) `alert` holds up the one JavaScript thread.

If the *sending* is really getting held up by the `alert`, you can fix that with `setTimeout`:

```
$(function() {
    url = "http://...../myscript.php";
    $.post(url, { action: 'my action', param: 'my parameter'}, {cache: false});
    setTimeout(function() { alert("Hello"); }, 0); // Defers it
});
```

If it's the callbacks that are getting held up, the best way to deal with that is to do something more modern than an `alert`, such as a nicely-styled absolutely-positioned `div` containing the message. If you want the message to be modal, you can do that yourself although there are some edge conditions around disabling the rest of the page; but there are also about a million "modal" plug-ins for jQuery that handle those edge conditions for you. (Both jQuery UI and Bootstrap provide them, and there are lots of others.)

Comment: I find it very surprising, too, and it is actually the sending (the script writes to a database and the entry is made *after* the alert is clicked away). Setting the timeout actually solves this problem. It raises the question though, whether this problem only occurs with alerts or with any code immediately after the ajax part. This would be annoying to circumvent.

Comment: @Samuel: I expect it's just `alert` and `confirm`, although possibly if you sent a *synchronous* ajax call after it might also hold things up. (But synchronous ajax calls are best avoided anyway.) `alert` and `confirm` are basically the only things that block the thread. I mean, you could have an endless loop, but then Safari would kill the script at some point anyway...

Comment: I added another case to the question. As expected (from the unexpected) the request is again sent *after* the summation. So while the request will always be sent at some point (ignoring while(true) for now), the timing is uncertain.